# ¿Cómo ejecutar script con DOM Modification Handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, firefox-webextensions

Estoy desarrollando un complemento de Firefox para Twitter que añade otro emblema (badge) al lado del de verificado.

**Problema:** cuando ejecuto el complemento desde `about:debugging` y entro a Twitter, todo parece funcionar bien como se ve en la captura de pantalla de abajo:

[image: Captura de pantalla de Twitter donde se muestra el complemento aparentemente funcionando.]

A medida que hago scroll hacia abajo, Twitter va generando y añadiendo al *DOM* nuevos tweets, ya sea con *lazyload* o algo parecido que simule una página infinita y sin final como se hace en muchas otras redes sociales con posts como Facebook, mostrando `article`'s cada vez más antiguos.

Por ende, los emblemas no aparecen en estos nuevos tweets cargados. Es decir, el script del complemento no carga para nuevos elementos, como se ve a continuación:

[image: Captura de pantalla de Twitter donde se muestra el complemento fallando en la carga del script.]

---

**Vías que he probado**

He tratado de hacer iniciar el script cada vez que haya cambios en la página. Esto soluciona el problema inicial, pero el emblema del área donde el script se había ejecutado por primera vez, se duplica.

---

Dejo los códigos más relevantes del complemento:

**`manifest.json`**

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "demo.js"]
    }
  ],
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage"]
}
```

---

Para que sea más sencillo de entender `demo.js`; lo único que hace el script es utilizar `$('').append('');` de JQuery para seleccionar dónde poner el emblema.

Dentro de `$()` está el selector donde debe ponerse el emblema y en `.append()` está el emblema en sí, que sigue la estructura de estilos de Twitter (por eso la extraña identificación de clases).

**`demo.js`**

```js
/* account switcher button */

$('div[data-testid="SideNav_AccountSwitcher_Button"] > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:first-of-type').append('<div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0" dir="auto"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></div>');

/* user cell */

$('li[data-testid="UserCell"] > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div:first-of-type').append('<div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0" dir="auto"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></div>');

/* heading */

$('h2[role="heading"] > div > div div').append('<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-poiln3 r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></span>');

/* tweet */

$('div[data-testid="tweet"] > div:nth-child(2) > div:first-of-type > div > div > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type a[role="link"] > div > div:first-of-type').append('<div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0" dir="auto"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></div>');

/* primary column */

$('div[data-testid="primaryColumn"] > div:first-of-type > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:first-of-type > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:first-of-type div').append('<span class="css-901oao css-16my406 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-poiln3 r-1b6yd1w r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></span>');

/* quoted tweet */

$('div[data-testid="tweet"] > div:last-of-type > div:last-of-type > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:last-of-type > div > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type > div > div > div > div > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type').append('<div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0" dir="auto"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></div>');

/* status */

$('div[data-testid="tweet"] > div:nth-child(2) > div:first-of-type > div > div > div:first-of-type > div:first-of-type a[role="link"] > div > div:first-of-type').append('<div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0" dir="auto"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></div>');
```

**Edito:** he encontrado una forma particular de que funcione pero me gustaría saber si existe otra un poco *menos bruta* o tosca de funcionar. Dejo el código del snippet a continuación.

```js
$(function(){
  window.setInterval(function() {
    [...]
  }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Hola, podrías probar de que cuando añades el circulo, añadir un tipo de clase al sitio donde ya has añadido el circulo, así cuando se ejecute el script haces que solo ponga el circulo en los sitios que debes y que no existe la clase, me explico?

Comment: El problema es que independientemente de lo que haga, en cuanto hagas scroll, desaparecerá en cierto punto el emblema...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer uso de la interfaz [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

> `MutationObserver` establece un mecanismo para reaccionar ante cambios en el DOM.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const targetNode = document.querySelector("#container");
const observerOptions = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  console.log('¡Hubo cambios!');
});
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);

//// OMITIR ESTA PARTE
//// Codigo para generar cambios en el DOM
window.setInterval(function() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerText = 'Hijo # ' + targetNode.children.length;
  targetNode.append(element);
}, 2 * 1000);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

---

#### Caso específico:

Una vez cargada por completo la página para detectar los nuevos *"tweets"* cargados dinámicamente y agregar el ícono solo a estos, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
// Luego de que cargó por completo la página...

const icon = '<div class="css-901oao r-18jsvk2 r-18u37iz r-1q142lx r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0" dir="auto"><svg class="r-13gxpu9 r-4qtqp9 r-yyyyoo r-1xvli5t r-9cviqr r-dnmrzs r-bnwqim r-1plcrui r-lrvibr" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-label="Infected person account" style="color: rgb(187, 55, 53)"><g><path d="M12 5c5 0 7 2 7 7s-2 7-7 7C7 19 5 17 5 12C5 7 7 5 12 5M12 2C6 2 2 6 2 12S6 22 12 22C18 22 22 18 22 12C22 6 18 2 12 2z"></path></g></svg></div>';
// Buscamos el elemento contenedor de tweets
const targetNode = document.querySelector('section.css-1dbjc4n[role="region"] > div > div');
// Definimos que mutaciones nos interesan detectar
const observerOptions = {
  childList: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {

  mutations.forEach(function (record) {
    // para cada nodo agregado
    record.addedNodes.forEach(function (element) {
      // buscamos donde esta el nombre y agregamos el icono
      element.querySelector('a[role="link"] > div > div:first-of-type').append(icon);
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(targetNode, observerOptions);
```

Comment: Al final me ha funcionado perfectamente tu código. Por encima no lo entendía pero dándole vueltas he conseguido solucionarlo. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @ortiz, he actualizado mi respuesta dando un poco mas de luz sobre como podrías utilizar la interfaz `MutationObserver`

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia habría entre elegir observar el elemento a cambiar, que todo el body, por ejemplo? ¿Rendimiento?

Comment: Si, mas que nada el rendimiento. Es probable el `body` sufra mas mutaciones (_por distintas causas_) que un elemento específico (_donde realmente esta sucediendo lo que estas necesitando_). Pero! por cuestiones de simplicidad es probable que te convenga usar el `body`

Comment: Podes verlo si lo ves de esta forma, por ejemplo, no es lo mismo analizar todo lo que pasa en el "mundo" cuando solo te interesa ver lo que pasa en "Japón"... pero depende mucho de cuantos "paises" necesitas controlar